# PL/SQL trigger to prevent duplicates

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, duplicates

I have a table called TBLAPPLICATION which holds data specifying an individual's ID number and a JobID of the job they have applied for. Each ID number can have an unlimited number of applications, providing the JobID is different every time, thus having no duplicate applications.

```
create or replace
   TRIGGER trg_duplicateapplication BEFORE INSERT ON tblapplication FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   IF :NEW.studentrecordnumber_fk_nn = :OLD.studentrecordnumber_fk_nn THEN
      IF :NEW.jobid_fk_nn = :OLD.jobid_fk_nn
         THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20003, 'Error: duplicate application. You have already applied for this position.');
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

So the above code doesn't work, and I wish it would. Could anyone please highlight my mistake? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it stands, your trigger is comparing the inserted values (`:NEW.studentrecordnumber_fk_nn` etc) with a non-existent `:OLD` (`:OLD` has no meaning to an `INSERT` trigger—[it's fields are always `null`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955)).

That aside, this should almost certainly be accomplished by DRI instead of a trigger at all— how about a unique index on `(studentrecordnumber_fk_nn, jobid_fk_nn)`?

Comment: Could I also just set a unique constraint on the jobid_fk_nn column in the application table?

Comment: If your business logic says that each job can only have one applicant, but that seems a little unlikely?

Comment: Ah, no, that's wrong. I will try and learn some DRI in that case. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MERGE statement in order to verify each couple (id,application) before inserting in the table (to check whether it is already in the table).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Regards,

Dariyoosh

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that in your table TBLAPPLICATION which identifier is unique (maybe JobID?) and which you want you not to be duplicated (maybe studentrecordnumber_fk_nn?). But I created a script to prevent duplication on studentrecordnumber_fk_nn.
And in my example “alphabet” I wrote a totally similar script to prevent the duplication: you cannot insert a letter which was inserted into the table earlier.

I hope it will help. 
z

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_duplicateapplication
BEFORE INSERT
ON tblapplication
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
counter integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO counter FROM
      (SELECT COUNT(rownum) FROM tblapplication a
        WHERE a.studentrecordnumber_fk_nn = :new.studentrecordnumber_fk_nn);
  IF counter = 1 THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20003,
  'Error: duplicate application. You have already applied for this position.');
  END IF;
END;
/


––The Alphabet


CREATE TABLE alphabet
(letter VARCHAR2(2));
INSERT INTO alphabet VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO alphabet VALUES ('B');
INSERT INTO alphabet VALUES ('C');
INSERT INTO alphabet VALUES ('D');

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insertvalue
BEFORE INSERT
ON alphabet
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE counter INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO counter FROM
      (SELECT COUNT(rownum) FROM alphabet a WHERE a.letter = :new.letter);
    IF counter = 1 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20012,'Duplicated value');
    END IF;
END;
/
```